# How do I enable TEE eclipse plugin on linux to clone a git repository in TFS 2013?

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013, team-explorer-everywhere

I have a TFS 2013 server setup in a windows active directory domain that hosts a git repository team project called "TestGit2". Windows clients are able to communicate with it just fine through visual studio and web access.

On a Ubuntu linux client, using eclipse, I have installed the latest Team Explorer Everywhere (TEE) client. Within the TFS plugin I can successfully do the following:

- connect to the server "TFS2013" and see the list of team project collections
- click on a team project collection and see available team projects
- select a team project and click finish to see the typical team explorer view options (Work Items, Reports, Builds, etc.)

From the linux machine I can open `http://tfs2013:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/TestGit2` which prompts me for credentials and then correctly displays the repository.

However, if I try to clone the repository in eclipse using either the EGit window or the "Import projects" option of the TEE plugin, I always get:

```
Error cloning the TestGit2 repository.
http://tfs2013:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/TestGit2: authentication not supported
```

I have enabled kerberos support through the TFS administration console and I have also tried enabling basic authentication within IIS on the TFS application tier but have not been able to resolve the issue.

What do I need to do to enable TEE to clone the git repository or at the very least, how can I go about troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not being able to look into this further for a long time, I finally got it working. The issue was that I was only switching the "Team Foundation Server" web site within IIS to use basic authentication and not going to the "tfs" virtual directory within that web site and setting basic authentication as the only authentication enabled. Once I did that, I was able to clone the repository from the linux box.